# Can a PrimitiveType have attributes?

Tags: uml

An UML Superstructure Specification says:

> A primitive type defines a predefined data type, without any relevant substructure (i.e., it has no parts in the context of UML). A primitive datatype may have an algebra and operations defined outside of UML, for example, mathematically.

But a PrimitiveType is derived from a DataType which can have attributes.

And also there is an example of PrimitiveTypes with attributes in a NIEM model:

http://niem-uml.org/ ([NIEM-UML-Machine-Readable-Files-gov-12-06-03](http://niem-uml.org/wpniem/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/NIEM-UML-Machine-Readable-Files-gov-12-06-03.zip) - NIEM-Reference-core.xmi: TextType, PersonNameTextType, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to UML specification PrimitiveType can not have attributes (even if it derives from DataType). I took a look at NIEM Model and I did not see any PrimitiveType with attribute so could be more precise about that?

Regards,

BR

Comment: Specification says that PrimitiveTypes can not have substructure, parts. But I do not understand what kind of parts they have in mind. You can find examples in NIEM-Reference-core.xmi (link in a first post). TextType has languageCode, partialIndicator, truncationIndicator attributes. PersonNameTextType has personNameInitialIndicator, sequenceID attributes.

Comment: Ok I found it. So for me it is an error with the NIEM model.
TextType for example should be a datatype instead of a primitivetype or it should remove its attributs..